# Why won't the Background color for radio button after checked not change?

Tags: html, css

I've searched around and checked various answers, but I'm having trouble with the following:
There are a couple caveats

1. Can't use Javascript or Jquery.
2. has to be pure CSS.

I want the background color of the label to change from Blue to Orange after the input is selected. It does not seem to work and I've checked around and read several answers from people, but none of them have worked for me and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

The CSS:

```
    .header-tabs-container {
        position: relative;
        float: center;
        left: 25%;
        clear: both;
        z-index: 2;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        white-space: normal;
        border: unset;
    }
    /* tabs names */
    .header-tabs-container .header-label {
        position: relative;
        padding: clamp(-1.5rem, -3.2rem + 8.8889vw, 3rem);
        font-size: clamp(0.95rem, -0.925rem + 8.333vw, 3rem);
        background-color: blue;
        color: #fff;
        cursor: pointer;
        user-select: none;
        text-align: center;
        z-index: 1;
        margin: 0px;
        border: white 1px solid;
        white-space: nowrap;
        border-radius: 40px 40px 0px 0px;
    }
    
    /* Hover effect on tabs names */
    .header-tabs-container .header-label:hover {
        background: orange;
        color: blue;
        transition: 0.2s;
    }
    
    /* Content area for tabs */
    .header-tab-content {
        position: relative;
        background: #eee;
        margin-top: -10px;
        width: 100%;
        min-height: 100vh;
        padding: 0px;
        float: left;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        z-index: 2;
        display: none;
        white-space: nowrap;
        border: 1px solid blue;
    }
    
    .header-tab-content:after {
        content: "";
        clear: both;
    }
    /* Hide input radio from users */
    input[name="header-tab"] {
        display: none;
    }
    /* Show tab when input checked */
    input[name="header-tab"]:checked + .header-tab-content {
        display: block;
        transition: 0.5s ease-out;
    }
    
    input[name="header-tab"]::after + .header-label {
        background-color: orange;
    }
```

The HTML

```
    <section class="header-tabs-container">
        <label class="header-label" for="header-tab1">Tab1</label><!--
            --><label class="header-label" for="header-tab2">Tab2</label>
      </section>
    
      <input name="header-tab" id="header-tab1" type="radio" checked/>
      <section class="header-tab-content">
        <h3>Test</h3>
           Content 
        </section>
    
      <input name="header-tab" id="header-tab2" type="radio" />
      <section class="header-tab-content">
          <h3> test</h3>
          content
        </section>
    
    </section>
```

Basically everything works as expected... Except I cannot, for the life of me, get the following to work at all.

```
    input[name="header-tab"]:checked + header-label {
    background-color: orange;
    }
```

Any ideas or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can't select previous siblings in CSS, you'll need move your `label` below `input` for it to work

Comment: as said, you cant select previos sibling elements but only following sibling elements with pure CSS. There is no way around scripting for you.

Comment: I removed the nesting for the label under the container - then moved it below the input.  However it still doesn't seem to work.  Would I have to move it in the html? I guess that would indicate it's impossible with pure CSS and the tabs I've configured. I would have to switch to the other method of tabs then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In CSS you cannot select previous siblings, therefore you'll need move `input` above your tabs and use `~` for sibling selections for the content:

```css
.header-tabs-container {
        position: relative;
        float: center;
/*            left: 25%;*/
        clear: both;
        z-index: 2;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        white-space: normal;
        border: unset;
    }
    /* tabs names */
    .header-tabs-container .header-label {
        position: relative;
        padding: clamp(-1.5rem, -3.2rem + 8.8889vw, 3rem);
        font-size: clamp(0.95rem, -0.925rem + 8.333vw, 3rem);
        background-color: blue;
        color: #fff;
        cursor: pointer;
        user-select: none;
        text-align: center;
        z-index: 1;
        margin: 0px;
        border: white 1px solid;
        white-space: nowrap;
        border-radius: 40px 40px 0px 0px;
    }
    
    /* Hover effect on tabs names */
    .header-tabs-container .header-label:hover {
        background: orange;
        color: blue;
        transition: 0.2s;
    }
    
    /* Content area for tabs */
    .header-tab-content {
        position: relative;
        background: #eee;
        margin-top: -10px;
        width: 100%;
        min-height: 100vh;
        padding: 0px;
        float: left;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        z-index: 2;
        display: none;
        white-space: nowrap;
        border: 1px solid blue;
    }
    
    .header-tab-content:after {
        content: "";
        clear: both;
    }
    /* Hide input radio from users */
    input[name="header-tab"] {
        display: none;
    }
    /* Show tab when input checked */
    input[name="header-tab"]:nth-of-type(1):checked ~ .header-tab-content:nth-of-type(1),
    input[name="header-tab"]:nth-of-type(2):checked ~ .header-tab-content:nth-of-type(2) {
        display: block;
        transition: 0.5s ease-out;
    }
    
    input[name="header-tab"]:checked + .header-label {
        background-color: orange;
    }
```

```html
<section class="header-tabs-container">
      <input name="header-tab" id="header-tab1" type="radio" checked/>
        <label class="header-label" for="header-tab1">Tab1</label>
      <input name="header-tab" id="header-tab2" type="radio" />
        <label class="header-label" for="header-tab2">Tab2</label>
    
      <section class="header-tab-content">
        <h3>Test</h3>
           Content 
        </section>
    
      <section class="header-tab-content">
          <h3> test</h3>
          content
        </section>
    
    </section>
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. Just have to adjust the width and tabs a bit more. Due to the limitation of the platform I'm putting this on, have to use pure CSS, but would using javascript make this much easier?

Comment: With javascript you'd have more control and would be easier to change/update/style

Answer (score 0):

> The + combinator matches the second element only if it immediately
> follows the first element.
> [CSS_Selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors)

Move the labels and inputs inside the same section and then try `~` or `+`.
`input` must be first.

Comment: You need to read more about selectors. You're just not targeting an element.